# HoloGraphLibrary issue in android 4

Tags: android, charts

use [HoloGraphLibrary](https://bitbucket.org/danielnadeau/holographlibrary/issues?status=new&status=open) in my app for charting. It works perfect in api below 10 but when I ran my app on Lenovo tablet with android 4 system I got this strange Log and I don't know where it comes from and why is that. This not happens every time. Sometimes I got no problem and everything is fine.

```
09-11 00:30:48.670: D/Input(6187): Couldn't open '/dev/touch' (No such file or 
directory)
09-11 00:30:48.670: D/Input(6187): tpd read x fail: Bad file number
09-11 00:30:48.670: D/Input(6187): tpd read y fail: Bad file number
09-11 00:30:48.872: D/Input(6187): m =9
09-11 00:30:48.872: D/Input(6187): xvelocity before =-2535.497314
09-11 00:30:48.872: D/Input(6187): yvelocity before =967.006104
09-11 00:30:48.872: D/Input(6187): 1 x[m-1]=354.731689
09-11 00:30:48.872: D/Input(6187): 1 x[0]=154.536575
09-11 00:30:48.873: D/Input(6187): 1 x[m-1]-x[0]=200.195114
09-11 00:30:48.873: D/Input(6187): 2 y[m-1]=576.119751
09-11 00:30:48.873: D/Input(6187): 2 y[0]=640.865234
09-11 00:30:48.873: D/Input(6187): 2 y[m-1]-y[0]=-64.745483
09-11 00:30:48.873: D/Input(6187): xvelocity=-2535.497314
09-11 00:30:48.873: D/Input(6187): yvelocity=967.006104
09-11 00:30:48.873: D/Input(6187):  fwq outVx=-2535.497314
09-11 00:30:48.873: D/Input(6187):  fwq outVy=967.006104
09-11 00:30:49.416: D/Input(6187): Couldn't open '/dev/touch' (No such file or directory)
09-11 00:30:49.416: D/Input(6187): tpd read x fail: Bad file number
09-11 00:30:49.416: D/Input(6187): tpd read y fail: Bad file number
09-11 00:30:49.638: D/Input(6187): m =9
09-11 00:30:49.639: D/Input(6187): xvelocity before =594.640076
09-11 00:30:49.639: D/Input(6187): yvelocity before =-2067.283691
09-11 00:30:49.639: D/Input(6187): 2 x[m-1]=325.463409
09-11 00:30:49.639: D/Input(6187): 2 x[0]=367.609741
09-11 00:30:49.639: D/Input(6187): 2 x[m-1]-x[0]=-42.146332
09-11 00:30:49.639: D/Input(6187): 1 y[m-1]=635.753723
09-11 00:30:49.639: D/Input(6187): 1 y[0]=489.224609
09-11 00:30:49.640: D/Input(6187): 1 y[m-1]-y[0]=146.529114
09-11 00:30:49.640: D/Input(6187): xvelocity=594.640076
09-11 00:30:49.640: D/Input(6187): yvelocity=-2067.283691
09-11 00:30:49.640: D/Input(6187):  fwq outVx=594.640076
09-11 00:30:49.640: D/Input(6187):  fwq outVy=-2067.283691
09-11 00:30:50.105: D/Input(6187): Couldn't open '/dev/touch' (No such file or directory)
09-11 00:30:50.106: D/Input(6187): tpd read x fail: Bad file number
09-11 00:30:50.106: D/Input(6187): tpd read y fail: Bad file number
09-11 00:30:50.225: D/Input(6187): m =9
09-11 00:30:50.225: D/Input(6187): xvelocity before =-2006.075195
09-11 00:30:50.226: D/Input(6187): yvelocity before =238.687546
09-11 00:30:50.226: D/Input(6187): 1 x[m-1]=349.463409
09-11 00:30:50.226: D/Input(6187): 1 x[0]=231.804871
09-11 00:30:50.226: D/Input(6187): 1 x[m-1]-x[0]=117.658539
09-11 00:30:50.226: D/Input(6187): 2 y[m-1]=528.412598
09-11 00:30:50.226: D/Input(6187): 2 y[0]=559.081543
09-11 00:30:50.226: D/Input(6187): 2 y[m-1]-y[0]=-30.668945
09-11 00:30:50.226: D/Input(6187): xvelocity=-2006.075195
09-11 00:30:50.227: D/Input(6187): yvelocity=238.687546
09-11 00:30:50.227: D/Input(6187):  fwq outVx=-2006.075195
09-11 00:30:50.227: D/Input(6187):  fwq outVy=238.687546
09-11 00:30:51.035: D/Input(6187): Couldn't open '/dev/touch' (No such file or directory)
09-11 00:30:51.035: D/Input(6187): tpd read x fail: Bad file number
09-11 00:30:51.035: D/Input(6187): tpd read y fail: Bad file number
09-11 00:30:51.228: D/Input(6187): m =9
09-11 00:30:51.228: D/Input(6187): xvelocity before =1474.926025
09-11 00:30:51.229: D/Input(6187): yvelocity before =-75.097374
09-11 00:30:51.229: D/Input(6187): 2 x[m-1]=311.414612
09-11 00:30:51.229: D/Input(6187): 2 x[0]=426.731689
09-11 00:30:51.229: D/Input(6187): 2 x[m-1]-x[0]=-115.317078
09-11 00:30:51.229: D/Input(6187): 1 y[m-1]=705.610596
09-11 00:30:51.229: D/Input(6187): 1 y[0]=693.683838
09-11 00:30:51.229: D/Input(6187): 1 y[m-1]-y[0]=11.926758
09-11 00:30:51.229: D/Input(6187): xvelocity=1474.926025
09-11 00:30:51.230: D/Input(6187): yvelocity=-75.097374
09-11 00:30:51.230: D/Input(6187):  fwq outVx=1474.926025
09-11 00:30:51.230: D/Input(6187):  fwq outVy=-75.097374
09-11 00:30:53.899: D/Input(6187): Couldn't open '/dev/touch' (No such file or directory)
09-11 00:30:53.899: D/Input(6187): tpd read x fail: Bad file number
09-11 00:30:53.899: D/Input(6187): tpd read y fail: Bad file number
09-11 00:30:54.050: D/Input(6187): m =9
09-11 00:30:54.050: D/Input(6187): xvelocity before =-1538.508911
09-11 00:30:54.050: D/Input(6187): yvelocity before =180.493057
09-11 00:30:54.050: D/Input(6187): 1 x[m-1]=419.707306
09-11 00:30:54.050: D/Input(6187): 1 x[0]=286.829254
09-11 00:30:54.051: D/Input(6187): 1 x[m-1]-x[0]=132.878052
09-11 00:30:54.051: D/Input(6187): 2 y[m-1]=567.600647
09-11 00:30:54.051: D/Input(6187): 2 y[0]=576.119751
09-11 00:30:54.051: D/Input(6187): 2 y[m-1]-y[0]=-8.519104
09-11 00:30:54.051: D/Input(6187): xvelocity=-1538.508911
09-11 00:30:54.051: D/Input(6187): yvelocity=180.493057
09-11 00:30:54.051: D/Input(6187):  fwq outVx=-1538.508911
09-11 00:30:54.051: D/Input(6187):  fwq outVy=180.493057
09-11 00:31:03.260: D/Input(6187): Couldn't open '/dev/touch' (No such file or directory)
09-11 00:31:03.260: D/Input(6187): tpd read x fail: Bad file number
09-11 00:31:03.260: D/Input(6187): tpd read y fail: Bad file number
09-11 00:31:03.323: D/Input(6187): m =5
09-11 00:31:03.324: D/Input(6187): xvelocity before =1355.720459
09-11 00:31:03.324: D/Input(6187): yvelocity before =-774.613281
09-11 00:31:03.324: D/Input(6187): 2 x[m-1]=247.609741
09-11 00:31:03.324: D/Input(6187): 2 x[0]=315.512177
09-11 00:31:03.324: D/Input(6187): 2 x[m-1]-x[0]=-67.902435
09-11 00:31:03.324: D/Input(6187): 1 y[m-1]=734.575684
09-11 00:31:03.324: D/Input(6187): 1 y[0]=700.499146
09-11 00:31:03.324: D/Input(6187): 1 y[m-1]-y[0]=34.076538
09-11 00:31:03.324: D/Input(6187): xvelocity=1355.720459
09-11 00:31:03.325: D/Input(6187): yvelocity=-774.613281
09-11 00:31:03.325: D/Input(6187):  fwq outVx=1355.720459
09-11 00:31:03.325: D/Input(6187):  fwq outVy=-774.613281
09-11 00:31:03.404: D/Input(6187): Couldn't open '/dev/touch' (No such file or directory)
09-11 00:31:03.404: D/Input(6187): tpd read x fail: Bad file number
09-11 00:31:03.405: D/Input(6187): tpd read y fail: Bad file number
09-11 00:31:03.493: D/Input(6187): m =8
09-11 00:31:03.493: D/Input(6187): xvelocity before =2092.001953
09-11 00:31:03.494: D/Input(6187): yvelocity before =-389.519012
09-11 00:31:03.494: D/Input(6187): 2 x[m-1]=464.780457
09-11 00:31:03.494: D/Input(6187): 2 x[0]=593.560974
09-11 00:31:03.494: D/Input(6187): 2 x[m-1]-x[0]=-128.780518
09-11 00:31:03.494: D/Input(6187): 1 y[m-1]=671.534058
09-11 00:31:03.494: D/Input(6187): 1 y[0]=656.199646
09-11 00:31:03.495: D/Input(6187): 1 y[m-1]-y[0]=15.334412
09-11 00:31:03.495: D/Input(6187): xvelocity=2092.001953
09-11 00:31:03.495: D/Input(6187): yvelocity=-389.519012
09-11 00:31:03.495: D/Input(6187):  fwq outVx=2092.001953
09-11 00:31:03.495: D/Input(6187):  fwq outVy=-389.519012
09-11 00:31:03.948: D/Input(6187): Couldn't open '/dev/touch' (No such file or directory)
09-11 00:31:03.948: D/Input(6187): tpd read x fail: Bad file number
09-11 00:31:03.948: D/Input(6187): tpd read y fail: Bad file number
09-11 00:31:04.088: D/Input(6187): m =9
09-11 00:31:04.088: D/Input(6187): xvelocity before =-1529.216919
09-11 00:31:04.089: D/Input(6187): yvelocity before =195.456085
09-11 00:31:04.089: D/Input(6187): 1 x[m-1]=493.463409
09-11 00:31:04.089: D/Input(6187): 1 x[0]=380.487793
09-11 00:31:04.089: D/Input(6187): 1 x[m-1]-x[0]=112.975616
09-11 00:31:04.090: D/Input(6187): 2 y[m-1]=697.091492
09-11 00:31:04.090: D/Input(6187): 2 y[0]=698.795288
09-11 00:31:04.090: D/Input(6187): 2 y[m-1]-y[0]=-1.703796
09-11 00:31:04.090: D/Input(6187): xvelocity=-1529.216919
09-11 00:31:04.090: D/Input(6187): yvelocity=195.456085
09-11 00:31:04.090: D/Input(6187):  fwq outVx=-1529.216919
09-11 00:31:04.090: D/Input(6187):  fwq outVy=195.456085
09-11 00:31:05.436: D/OpenGLRenderer(6187): Flushing caches (mode 0)
09-11 00:31:05.975: D/OpenGLRenderer(6187): Flushing caches (mode 1)
```

and of course there's no chart plot.